# Diagonal Array Traverse Top Right to Bottom Left

Tags: arrays, 2d

I'm wanting to traverse a 2d array diagonally from the top right to bottom left, but struggling to find a pattern to implement. By searching the site, I'm only managing to find searches for an array diagonally from the top left.

Example Array

```
  0 1 2 3
0 G D B A
1 K H E C
2 N L I F
3 P O M J 

Expected output should be: 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP'
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: which technology (programming language) are you using?

Comment: Personally I am using java for this, but any language works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected output by the following code:

The approach is to traverse the array along all the diagonal lines. We get the initial column index for each diagonal lines. Total diagonal lines would be `ROW + COL -1`. Then we count the elements along each diagonal line. After that we just traverse the diagonal line to get the output.

```
 private void zigZagFromTopRightTillBottomLeft(char[][] dp){

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    int ROW = 4;
    int COL = 4;

    for (int line = 1; line <= (ROW + COL - 1); line++) {

        int start_col = Math.min(COL-1, ROW + COL -1 - line);

        int count = Math.min(Math.min(line, (start_col+1)), ROW);

        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            list.add(char[Math.min(ROW, line) - j- 1][(start_col - j)]);

        System.out.println();
    }

    System.out.println(list);
}
```